# joomla/virtuemart - no layout on login page

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

i'm working on a joomla 1.5 with virtuemart 1.1.8. I'm not an experienced user of joomla, and one of my modifications exited the virtuemart page "shop.registration" (register page) out of the theme's layout : i miss the header and the footer.

Did anyone know how joomla and virtuemart templating system works ? It's my first use of virtuemart, and the 2nd of joomla.

Thanks.

Comment: Normally this will never happen until you load separate template for that page.Check your section and what change you made anything related to the template change ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtuemart prior to version 2.x does not use the Joomla! template system, instead it uses it's own "themes" mechanism which is frankly horrible.  The main problem is that most people hack the standard theme and then when and update comes along it get over-written by the update.

You can still read about the old [1.1.x style of themes](http://virtuemart.net/documentation/Developer_Manual/Modifying_the_Layout.html) on the [Virtuemart Developer documentation](http://virtuemart.net/documentation/Developer_Manual/) website.

Also, you should update to [Virtuemart 1.1.9](http://virtuemart.net/downloads) as it includes some serious fixes.

Comment: 1.1.x guide saved my day, since i knew there was no relation between joomla and VM templates i was able to search at the right place. Thanks